# How to Collapse tab-pane content in togglable Tabs after view?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

In Togglable tabs, when the page loads, no pane-content appears. but as we click any of tab, corresponding content appears on screen, and keeps changing a we click other tabs. But Once the tab-content is appeared on screen, it always remains on screen, it changes with other tabs click , but never disappears until complete web page is refreshed again. Please guide is there any way I can make the content disappear.

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
  <li class="active"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#home">Home</a></li>
  <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#menu1">Menu 1</a></li>
  <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#menu2">Menu 2</a></li>
</ul>

<div class="tab-content">
  <div id="home" class="tab-pane">
    <h3>HOME</h3>
    <p>Some content.</p>
  </div>
  <div id="menu1" class="tab-pane">
    <h3>Menu 1</h3>
    <p>Some content in menu 1.</p>
  </div>
  <div id="menu2" class="tab-pane">
    <h3>Menu 2</h3>
    <p>Some content in menu 2.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What version of Bootstrap are you using?

Comment: I am using Bootstrap 3.3.7

Answer (score 0):

Just need to add "active" class to what pane you want visible on load. Same as the tabs. See below

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
  <li class="active"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#home">Home</a></li>
  <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#menu1">Menu 1</a></li>
  <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#menu2">Menu 2</a></li>
</ul>

<div class="tab-content">
  <div id="home" class="tab-pane active">
    <h3>HOME</h3>
    <p>Some content.</p>
  </div>
  <div id="menu1" class="tab-pane">
    <h3>Menu 1</h3>
    <p>Some content in menu 1.</p>
  </div>
  <div id="menu2" class="tab-pane">
    <h3>Menu 2</h3>
    <p>Some content in menu 2.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```